# How to make validation using pipes?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I am learning functional programming in Javascript and am sure this question will sound stupid.

Say I have some data:

```js
const data = {
  name: 'someName',
  number: 10
}
```

and I want to validate this data using pipes (should I even use pipes for that?). First, I define some functions that will be used in the validation:

```js
// will be used to validate name
const isStrNotEmpty = str => str !== ''
const createStrDelimiter = limit => str => str < limit
const isStrNotLongerThan15 = createStrDelimiter(15)
```

Then I define `pipe`:

```js
const pipe = (...fns) => t => fns.reduce((a, b) => b(a), t)
```

Then I make a pipe that validates the data's name:

```js
const validateDataName = data => pipe(
  isStrNotEmpty,
  isStrNotLongerThan15
)(data.name)
```

The thing is... I know I am doing something wrong. Terribly wrong.

Isn't the pipe basically getting `isStrNotEmpty`'s boolean value and passing it to `isStrNotLongerThan15` instead of the `name`?

How do I use validation with pipes in this context?

Comment: You are correct. Each function is passing its result into the next. You could probably write your functions to return the original string if test passes or `false` if either the input was `false` or the string didn't pass the test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right in that pipes are generally used when you want to run a function (`f`), and then pass the output of `f` to another function `g`. This can continue for many functions and isn't just restricted to two.

In your case, the behaviour you want isn't piping, since the output of `isStrNotEmpty` does not need to be fed into `isStrNotLongerThan15`. Instead, you want to check if *every* function passes and returns true:

```js
const data = {
  name: 'someName',
  number: 10
};

const isStrNotEmpty = str => str !== ''
const createStrDelimiter = limit => str => str.length < limit
const isStrNotLongerThan15 = createStrDelimiter(15)

const all = (...fns) => t => fns.every(f => f(t))

const validateDataName = data => all(
  isStrNotEmpty,
  isStrNotLongerThan15
)(data.name);

console.log(validateDataName(data)); // true
console.log(validateDataName({name: ''})); // false
console.log(validateDataName({name: '123456789012345'})); // false (len = 15)
```

You could technically force piping here if you really want, by returning the result of the previous function along with the origin input, but imo the above would be cleaner:

```js
const data = {
  name: 'someName',
  number: 10
}

const isStrNotEmpty = str => str !== ''
const createStrDelimiter = limit => str => str < limit
const isStrNotLongerThan15 = createStrDelimiter(15)

const pipe = (...fns) => t => fns.reduce((a, b) => b(a), t)

const validateDataName = data => pipe(
  name => [name, isStrNotEmpty(name)],
  ([name, res]) => res && isStrNotLongerThan15(name)
)(data.name);

console.log(validateDataName(data));
```

As seen in the above snippet, you need to transform each function to fit the form of:

```
([input, prevResult]) => [input, prevResult && currentFunc(input)]
```

You could write a helper function to do this for you, as seen below:

```js
const data = {
  name: 'someName',
  number: 10
};

const isStrNotEmpty = str => str !== ''
const createStrDelimiter = limit => str => str.length < limit
const isStrNotLongerThan15 = createStrDelimiter(15)

const pipe = (...fns) => t => fns.reduce((a, b) => b(a), t);

const next = ([, next]) => next;
const all = (...fns) => t => next(pipe(
  ...fns.map(f => ([t, r]) => [t, r && f(t)])
)([t,true]));

const validateDataName = data => all(
  isStrNotEmpty,
  isStrNotLongerThan15
)(data.name);

console.log(validateDataName(data)); // true
console.log(validateDataName({name: ""})); // false
console.log(validateDataName({name: "123456789012345"})); // false (len = 15)
```

However, these two last examples don't short-circuit (the function calls are short-circuited, just not the iteration) as we still need to iterate through each function passed though. Unlike the last two examples, the first code snippet does short-circuit, meaning as soon as we find that a function has returned false we can stop all iteration. As a result, I would favour the first method of the piping approach.

Comment: i see. it's all... functions. thank you so much! i know this is out of the scope of this question and I don't wanna bother you; how would I return an error if, for instance, `isStrNotEmpty` fails? do I have to use Either Monads or something like that?

Comment: @kibe no worries. I've added another snippet which acts as a helper method to achieve the same result as the second. In terms of error handling, you could give [this article](https://itnext.io/either-monad-a-functional-approach-to-error-handling-in-js-ffdc2917ab2) a read which might help

Comment: awesome, thank you! can you suggest me resources for learning functional programming in Javascript?

Comment: @kibe I personally don't know of any JS functional programming resources as I learnt most of this stuff at Univerity, but I'm sure there would be some good video tutorials online. Another option would be to try and learn a language such as Haskell, which requires you to use FP. You can then carry the concepts learnt from there into the JS world.